# Calculate Duration between two dates (Month and Year will be Considered)

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff

I have two dates
`06-Jan-2009`  and  `12-Dec-2010`

I want to calculate the date difference between these two dates.. (basis on the month and year).
I want to get the answer 2 Year.

But if dates is `06-Jan-2009` And `12-Oct-2010`
then I need 10 Months as output.

Comment: What you want is DateDiff function, here is the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx):

Comment: So, you want to round up any partial months then? (Since your example is 1 year, 11 months and 6 days)

Comment: YEs.. but if more than 1 year then year and month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Declare @SDate DateTime ='06-Jan-2009'
Declare @EDate DateTime ='12-Oct-2009'


select case when DateDiff(M,@sDate,@EDate) <=12 
            then DateDiff(M,@sDate,@EDate) 
            else Round( ( Convert(Decimal(18,0)
                                   ,DateDiff(M,@sDate,@EDate)/12.0)),0) end
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. You did not mention in your inital question

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @Birthdate datetime 
declare @AsOnDate datetime

declare @years int
declare @months int 
declare @days int
declare @hours int
declare @minutes int 

--NOTE: date of birth must be smaller than As on date, 
--else it could produce wrong results
set @Birthdate = '1989-11-30 9:27 pm' --birthdate
set @AsOnDate  = Getdate()            --current datetime

--calculate years
select @years = datediff(year,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate)

--calculate months if it's value is negative then it 
--indicates after __ months; __ years will be complete
--To resolve this, we have taken a flag @MonthOverflow...
declare @monthOverflow int
select @monthOverflow = case when datediff(month,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate) - 
  ( datediff(year,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate) * 12) <0 then -1 else 1 end
--decrease year by 1 if months are Overflowed
select @Years = case when @monthOverflow < 0 then @years-1 else @years end
select @months =  datediff(month,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate) - (@years * 12) 

--as we do for month overflow criteria for days and hours 
--& minutes logic will followed same way
declare @LastdayOfMonth int
select @LastdayOfMonth =  datepart(d,DATEADD
    (s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@AsOnDate)+1,0)))

select @days = case when @monthOverflow<0 and 
    DAY(@Birthdate)> DAY(@AsOnDate) 
then @LastdayOfMonth + 
  (datepart(d,@AsOnDate) - datepart(d,@Birthdate) ) - 1  
      else datepart(d,@AsOnDate) - datepart(d,@Birthdate) end 

declare @hoursOverflow int
select @hoursOverflow = case when datepart(hh,@AsOnDate) -
    datepart(hh,@Birthdate) <0 then -1 else 1 end
select @hours = case when @hoursOverflow<0 then 24 + 
  datepart(hh,@AsOnDate) - datepart(hh,@Birthdate) 
  else datepart(hh,@AsOnDate) - datepart(hh,@Birthdate) end

declare @minutesOverflow int
select @minutesOverflow = case when datepart(mi,@AsOnDate) - 
    datepart(mi,@Birthdate) <0 then -1 else 1 end
select @minutes = case when @hoursOverflow<0 
    then 60 - (datepart(mi,@AsOnDate) - 
  datepart(mi,@Birthdate)) else abs(datepart
      (mi,@AsOnDate) - datepart(mi,@Birthdate)) end

select
 @Months=case when @days < 0 or DAY(@Birthdate)> DAY(@AsOnDate) then @Months-1 else @Months end

Declare @lastdayAsOnDate int;
set @lastdayAsOnDate = datepart(d,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@AsOnDate),0)));
Declare @lastdayBirthdate int;
set @lastdayBirthdate =  datepart(d,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@Birthdate)+1,0)));

if (@Days < 0) 
(
    select @Days = case when( @lastdayBirthdate > @lastdayAsOnDate) then
        @lastdayBirthdate + @Days
    else
        @lastdayAsOnDate + @Days
    end
)
print  convert(varchar,@years)   + ' year(s),   '  +
       convert(varchar,@months)  + ' month(s),   ' +
       convert(varchar,@days)    + ' day(s),   '   +
       convert(varchar,@hours)   + ':'             + 
       convert(varchar,@minutes) + ' hour(s)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Round( (
Convert(Decimal(18,2),DateDiff(M,'06-Jan-2009','12-Dec-2010')/12.0)),0)
as Years
```

Answer (score 0):

Please tried with below query

```
Declare @SDate DateTime ='01-Jan-2009'
Declare @EDate DateTime ='12-Oct-2009'

SET  @EDate  = DATEADD(M, 1, @EDate)
select DateDiff(M,@sDate,@EDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be work for me:

```
DECLARE @start DATETIME='01-Jan-2008'
DECLARE @end DATETIME='10-Nov-2011'
DECLARE @duration INT

--SELECT @start = '2011-10-10', @end = '2013-10-10'
--select DATEPART(dd,@start)
SET @Start = Dateadd(DAY, -( Datepart(DD, @Start) - 1 ), @Start)

SET @end = Dateadd(DAY, -( Datepart(day, @end) - 1 ), @end)
SET @end = Dateadd(day, Day(Dateadd(mm, Datediff(mm, -1, @end), -1)), @end)

SELECT @duration = Datediff(mm, @Start, @end)

SELECT CASE
    WHEN @duration = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN @duration%12 = 0 THEN( CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @duration / 12) + ' Year ' )
    WHEN @duration > 12 THEN( CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @duration / 12) + ' Year ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @duration % 12) + ' Month ' )
    ELSE (SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @duration % 12) + ' Month')
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @Birthdate datetime 
declare @AsOnDate datetime

declare @years varchar(4)
declare @months varchar(3) 
declare @days varchar(3)
declare @hours varchar(3)
declare @minutes varchar(2) 

set @Birthdate = '1989-11-30 9:27 AM' --birthdate
set @AsOnDate  = getdate()        --current datetime

select @years = datediff(year,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate)
select @months = datediff(month,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate) - 
    ( datediff(year,@Birthdate,@AsOnDate) * 12) 
select @days = datepart(d,@AsOnDate) - datepart(d,@Birthdate) 
select @hours = datepart(hh,@AsOnDate) - datepart(hh,@Birthdate) 
select @minutes = abs(datepart(mi,@AsOnDate) - datepart(mi,@Birthdate))

print  @years   + ' year(s),   '  +
       @months  + ' month(s),   ' +
       @days    + ' day(s),   '   +
       @hours   + ':'             + @minutes + ' hour(s)'
```

**OUT PUT:**

[image]